# How do I put the exception message from gsoap then send to a std::string?

Tags: c++, gsoap

I know the code below could print the exception, but how do I put the exception message to the `std::string`?

The code below prints the exception

```
    proxy.soap_stream_fault(std::cout);
```

Answer (score 2):

`soap_stream_fault` takes any `std::ostream&`, according to its prototype. Just create a `stringstream` (or `ostringstream`). This would probably do it:

```
std::stringstream strstream;
proxy.soap_stream_fault(strstream);
std::string str{strstream.str()};
```